# JTable Server Side Sorting

Tags: java, swing

I have a Client/Server app and my JTables are paginated, it shows only a range of the data. Now I would like to handle the sorting but server side. How can I customize  the default sorting implementation?

Comment: *"Now I would like to handle the sorting but server side"*  Why?  It seems an unnecessary burden on the network and server.  BTW - What is the feature you are trying to implement here, as you might explain it to an end user?  I suspect that whatever that feature is, you are going about it the wrong way.

Comment: eg. In db I have 1.000.000 of records and I cannot show all those records in my jtable in the client app, but I'm going to show only the first 100. If the user click on one column header for sorting the records, the client app needs to fetch others 100 records ordered by the new sort criteria.

Comment: Why not add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works but I'm sure that it is not the best! :)

```
...
final MyTableModel myModel = new MyTableModel();
final MySorter mySorter = new MySorter(myModel);
mySorter.addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {

  @Override
  public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
    // server side sorting
    sortDataByColumn(mySorter.getColumnToSort());
  }
});

JTable table = new JTable();
table.setModel(myModel);
table.setRowSorter(mySorter);
...

class MySorter extends TableRowSorter<TableModel> {      

  private String columnToSort;

  public MySorter(AbstractTableModel model) {
    super(model);
  }

  @Override
  public void sort() {
    // do nothing! because server side sorting
  }

  @Override
  protected void fireSortOrderChanged() {
    // build a string like [+-]column_identifier.
    // where + is for ASC and - for DESC ordering
    final SortKey k = getSortKeys().get(0);
    final String colName = getModel().getTableColumnModel()
      .getColumn(k.getColumn()).getIdentifier().toString();

    if (colName != null && !colName.isEmpty()) {
      columnToSort = (k.getSortOrder() == SortOrder.ASCENDING ? '+' : '-') + colName;
    } else {
      columnToSort = null;
    }
    super.fireSortOrderChanged();
  }

  public String getColumnToSort() {
    return columnToSort;
  }
}
```